# Updating the GUI when some thing changes

Tags: python, tkinter

I was trying to make a program that generates random passwords.

This is the code.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import string

# recourses&def
string.digits
string.ascii_letters
abc  = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
num  = random.choice(string.digits)
pun  = random.choice(string.punctuation)
abc2 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
num2 = random.choice(string.digits)
pun2 = random.choice(string.punctuation)
abc3 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
num3 = random.choice(string.digits)
pun3 = random.choice(string.punctuation)
abc4 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
num4 = random.choice(string.digits)
pun4 = random.choice(string.punctuation)

password = abc+num+pun+abc2+"  "+num2+pun2+abc3+num3+"  "+pun3+abc4+num4+pun4


def myclick():
    print(password)
    label2 = Label(window, text="    ")
    label2.config(text=password,font=("Serif", 50, "bold"),bg="#bfbcbb")
    label2.config()
    label2.pack()
    


# window
window = Tk()
window.title("Random PasswordS")



# the label
label = Label(window, text=" Welcome To Random Passwords ")
label.config(font=("Ink Free", 50, "bold"))
label.config(fg="#fc0331")
label.config(bg="#03fce7")
label.grid(row=0, column=0)

# button
theButton = Button(window, text="Click here!",
                   padx=20, pady=5, command=myclick)
theButton.grid(row=1, column=0)


# mainloop
window.mainloop()
```

The problem is I want the password to be replaced with new one on the same label when I click the button again but I don’t know what function I should use.
could someone help me with this?

Comment: The code that generates a random password needs to happen every time the button is clicked, so it needs to be inside your `myclick` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of @martineau is good.And here's how I would do it and
I use StringVar!

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import string


def generate_password():
    result = []
    for _ in range(3):
        abc  = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
        num  = random.choice(string.digits)
        pun  = random.choice(string.punctuation)
        result.append(abc+num+pun)
    return "  ".join(result)

def myclick():
    password = generate_password()
    src.set(password)
    label2.grid()
# window
window = Tk()
window.title("Random PasswordS")
src=StringVar()

# the label
label = Label(window, text="Welcome To Random Passwords",
              font=("Ink Free", 50, "bold"),
              fg="#fc0331",
              bg="#03fce7")
label.grid(row=0, column=0)

# The other label.
label2 = Label(window, textvariable=src, font=("Serif", 50, "bold"), bg="#bfbcbb")
label2.grid(row=1, column=0)
label2.grid_remove()  # Hide it initially.


# button
theButton = Button(window, text="Click here!", padx=20, pady=5, command=myclick)
theButton.grid(row=2, column=0)

# mainloop
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't need the `window.update()` call.

Comment: Absolutely unnecessary to use a `StringVar` here. IMO, such a minute change if you feel is _important_ you should rather post it as a comment below the other answer as a suggestion, rather than taking the code and posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it. The main idea is to create the `Label` widget *once* that will contain the password ahead of time, and then just configure the text display on it whenever it needs to be using the widget's `config()` method instead of creating a new `Label` whenever the `Button` is clicked.

To initially hide this `Label`, its `grid_remove()` method is also called right after it's created to temporarily make it invisible, then in the `myclick()` function, its `grid()` method is called with no arguments because the initial ones will be remembered — which will make it visible if it wasn't already.

Note I also added a `generate_password()` function that `myclick()` calls each time it's called so the password displayed will change every time the `Button` is clicked.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import string


def generate_password():
    result = []
    for _ in range(3):
        abc  = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
        num  = random.choice(string.digits)
        pun  = random.choice(string.punctuation)
        result.append(abc+num+pun)
    return "  ".join(result)

def myclick():
    password = generate_password()
    label2.config(text=password)
    label2.grid()

# window
window = Tk()
window.title("Random PasswordS")

# the label
label = Label(window, text="Welcome To Random Passwords",
              font=("Ink Free", 50, "bold"),
              fg="#fc0331",
              bg="#03fce7")
label.grid(row=0, column=0)

# The other label.
label2 = Label(window, text="", font=("Serif", 50, "bold"), bg="#bfbcbb")
label2.grid(row=1, column=0)
label2.grid_remove()  # Hide it initially.


# button
theButton = Button(window, text="Click here!", padx=20, pady=5, command=myclick)
theButton.grid(row=2, column=0)

# mainloop
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.Martineau but I have a question I know that "join" method can only be used with tuples. so where is the tuple here I couldn't notice it? and very sorry to ask again but what exactly made this password change every time the button is clicked. is it the loop?

Comment: Omar: You're welcome. The `generate_password()` function is using the [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method that *strings* have to combining the 3 strings in the `results` *list* together with a `"  "` string between each of them. All `join()` needs it something iterable and both tuples and lists are.